# modify metadata using xattr (OSX terminal)

Tags: macos, xattr

I'm trying to use terminal and the xattr to modify an extended metadata entry.

It looks simple, but I don't have any success.
Currently I tried something like below:

```
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDisplayName 'fileName.localized' 'somePath.localized'
```

I returns no error, but nothing is changed.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Thanks
Andreas